# Using SQL and Python (CS50 PSET7)

Tags: python, sql, database, sqlite, cs50

There are two parts to this programme.

1. In import.py, to write a program that imports data from a CSV spreadsheet. the CSV spreadsheet contains full names, birth, year, and I would like to separate the full name to "first name", "middle name", "last name". My programme is as follows:

**import.py**

```
from csv import reader
from sys import argv, exit
from cs50 import SQL
import csv
import sys

# check command line arguments
if len(sys.argv) != 2:
    print(f"Usage: import.py .csv")
    exit(1)

if not argv[1].endswith(".csv"):
    print(f"Usage: import.py .csv 3 arg")
    exit(1)

# variables
db = SQL("sqlite:///students.db")

total = 0
first = []
middle = []
last = []
house = []
birth = []

with open(argv[1], 'r') as csvfile:
    data = csv.reader(csvfile)

    for row in data:
        names = row[0]
        house = row[1]
        birth = row[2]
    total = total + 1

# split names

    if len(names) == 2:
        first.append(names[0])
        middle.append('None')
        last.append(names[1])

    if len(names) == 3:
        first.append(names[0])
        middle.append(middle[2])
        last.append(names[2])

    for i in range(total - 1):
        db.execute("INSERT INTO students (first, middle, last, house, birth) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?)", first[i], middle[i], last[i], house[i], birth[i])
```

2. For the second part, roster.py, the task is towrite a programme that prints a list of students for a given house in alphabetical order.

E.g. for

```
$ python roster.py Gryffindor
```

The programme should return e.g.

```
Hermione Jean Granger, born 1979
Harry James Potter, born 1980
Ginevra Molly Weasley, born 1981
Ronald Bilius Weasley, born 1980
```

My code is as follows:

**roster.py**

```
from csv import reader
from sys import argv, exit
from cs50 import SQL
import sys

db = SQL("sqlite:///students.db")

# check command line arguments
if len(sys.argv) != 2:
    print(f"Usage: python roster.py house")
    exit(1)

house = sys.argv[1]

# if sys.argv[1].lower() != "slytherin" or sys.argv[1].lower() != "gryffindor" or sys.argv[1].lower() != "ravenclaw" or sys.argv[1].lower() != "hufflepuff":
  #  print("choose a house!")
   # exit(1)

rows = db.execute('SELECT * FROM students WHERE house = (?) ORDER BY last, first', sys.argv[1])

for row in rows:
    print(row['first'],end=" ")

    if row["middle"] != 'None':
        print(row['middle'],end=" ")

    print(row['last'],end=", ")
    print("born ", row['birth'])
```

I've been stuck for really long and can't see why the code is not printing out the names! Would really appreciate some help, please!

Answer (score 0):

There are three issues with import.py,
first the `total` is at wrong indentation,
secondly you are not appending to the lists, instead overwriting it,
lastly, your create statement is incorrect.

See if this helps -

```
total = 0
first = []
middle = []
last = []
house = []
birth = []

with open(argv[1], 'r') as csvfile:
    data = csv.reader(csvfile)

    for row in data:
        names = row[0].split()
        house = row[1]
        birth = row[2]
        total = total + 1

        # split names

        if len(names) == 2:
            first.append(names[0])
            middle.append('None')
            last.append(names[1])
        
        if len(names) == 3:
            first.append(names[0])
                middle .append(names[1])
                last.append(names[2])

db.execute("CREATE TABLE students (first char(100), middle char(100), last char(100), house char(100), birth char(100))")

for i in range(total):
        db.execute("INSERT INTO students (first, middle, last, house, birth) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?)", first[i], middle[i], last[i], house[i], birth[i])
```

As you can see I have seperated the CREATE and INSERT seperately. Since I don't know the datatype of birth I have assumed it to be CHAR, please modify as per your need.

Comment: Thanks very much for your help! I no longer receive errors, but nothing prints out after i run python roster.py hufflepuff or any of the houses. 

Any advice is greatly appreciated!

Comment: Your CREATE statement was not correct, please see I have edited last lines of code in my answer.

Comment: thanks, however, when i run "python roster.py Slytherin" or any of the houses, i am still unable to retrieve any names.

Comment: Please declare house = [] and birth = [] before opening csv, also please try to enter the house name in the exact case as in the csv file while calling the second script.

Comment: thanks, ok, have added house = [] and birth = [] before opening csv. still not output when i run "python roster.py Slytherin". not sure if there are mistakes in roster.py? I've also updated my code above.

Comment: names = row[0].split() please update this in your import.py, I have updated in my answer :) Apart from that I hope you have students.db already made in your database

Comment: thanks, have added .splt() and yes, i have students.db in my folder, but am still not receiving any content when i run "python roster.py Slytherin"!

Comment: Do you still need help?